# Can we access protected variable in different package with the help of parent class

Tags: java, inheritance, protected, access-modifiers

I make a variable that has been protected in the parent class but when I try to access it from subclass with the help of the parent class name I am unable to access it. As parent class and subclass are in different packages.

I tried the below code, **can I know why I am unable to access it**.

```
package basic;

public class AccessModifiers {

    protected int age;

    public AccessModifiers() {
        super();
    }

    public AccessModifiers(int age) {
        super();
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}


package inheritance;

import basic.AccessModifiers;

public class Inheritance extends AccessModifiers {

    public Inheritance(int age) {
        super(age);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Inheritance inheritance = new Inheritance(23);
        System.out.println("Age:" + AccessModifiers.age);
    }
}
```

Comment: `age` is not a `static` field, so you cannot access it as such. Why don't you simply call `inheritance.getAge()`?

Comment: Calling `super()` without extending anything (`Object` that is) is also kind of superfluous.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with the access modifier, but rather with the field not being [static](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html). Just replace

`AccessModifiers.age`

with

`inheritance.age`

Note that `protected` access allows you to access the field from the child class. Once you move the `main` method to another class that is not a subclass or in a different package, the field would no longer be accessible, and you would use the `getAge()` method instead.